# Angularjs ui grid with grouping column sequence is getting jumbled up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I am using AngularJs ui grid with grouping. The table is displaying fine but the problem I am facing is that the months sequence in the table is getting jumbled up.  Please find my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQbSPokIeT5abTp819BB?p=preview). In the table the Months are appearing in the jumbled up sequence 11-14, 05-15, 04-15, ... 02-15. But I need it in the sequence of 11-14, 12-14, 01-15, 02-15, 03-15, 04-15, 05-15. Can any one help me to fix it?

I am using the following for to get colDefs:

```
$scope.getColumnDefsForUiGrid = function(columns) {
     var colDef = [];
     colDef.push({
         name: 'mode',
         grouping: {
             groupPriority: 0
         },
         displayName: 'Type',
         enableCellEdit: false,
         width: '5%'
     });
     colDef.push({
         name: 'service',
         displayName: 'Catg',
         enableCellEdit: false,
         width: '5%'
     });
     angular.forEach(columns, function(value, key) {
         colDef.push({
             name: key,
             displayName: value,
             enableCellEdit: true,
             aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
             width: '5%'
         })
     });
     return colDef;
 };
```

Comment: Actually your ui-grid columns are in the exact same order than your  $scope.columns. If you want to change the order, you can reorder this object.

Comment: How can I do it in getColumnDefsForUiGrid ?

Comment: I just want months in correct sequence order.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MkE58U9mefiRyMTC4Ohf?p=preview Now they are. But i'm not sure i get your problem. In your application does this column def is hard-coded too ? or are the column dynamic ?

Comment: It is dynamic. First I need to get mode and then service after that all the months should be displayed sequential order. After pushing Mode and Service into colDef, I have the flexibility to change the logic while looping through using angular.forEach(columns, function( value, key ). Can we something here in order to keep the sequence in the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for your problem
[you can see it working on this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UfOZTR81bb8mBz2FzkC?p=preview)

```
$scope.getColumnDefsForUiGrid = function( columns ){
        var colDef = [];                        
        colDef.push({name: 'mode', grouping: { groupPriority: 0 }, displayName: 'Type', enableCellEdit: false, width: '5%'});
        colDef.push({name: 'service',  displayName: 'Catg', enableCellEdit: false, width: '5%'});

        //I split the monthColumns into an other array                      
        var monthCol = [];
        angular.forEach(columns, function( value, key ) {
              monthCol.push({name: key, displayName: value, enableCellEdit: true, aggregationType : uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, width: '5%' })
        });

        //I sort this array using a custom function
        monthCol.sort(function(a,b){
              a = a.displayName.split("-");
              b = b.displayName.split("-");
              if(a[1] < b[1]){
                  return -1;
              }else if (a[1] > b[1]){
                  return 1;
              }else {
                  if(a[0] < b[0]){
                     return -1;
                  }else{
                    return 1;
                  }
              }
        });

   //I concat the two array
   return colDef.concat(monthCol);
};
```

Comment: Yes, Accepted the Answer. Thanks